# Present Scene with Sprite Kit in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

So when i start my game the you can play until you die, then the main menu Scene is presented and if you touch on the screen in the main menu you should load the GameScene again but i get an Error, i use this code to present the GameScene:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let revealGameScene = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
    let goToGameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    goToGameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
    self.view?.presentScene(goToGameScene, transition:revealGameScene)
}
```

and the Same to present the main menu when you die which works perfectly fine but for some reason it doesn't work when i try to present the GameScene from the main menu

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: any idea why? i can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think that there has to be an error outside of what you're showing us. I can create a very basic project that starts on a MenuScene (directed there by the GameViewController), when you click anywhere on the MenuScene it takes you to the GameScene. In the GameScene if you click a green box it takes you back to the MenuScene. And round and round you go.

Take a look at the code and see if anything different from yours

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var menuScene: MenuScene!
    var skView: SKView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create and configure the scene.
        skView = self.view as! SKView

        menuScene = MenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        menuScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true


        // Present the scene.
        skView.presentScene(menuScene)
    }
}

class MenuScene: SKScene {

    override init(size: CGSize) {

        super.init(size: size)

        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        let background = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: self.size)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(background)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let revealGameScene = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
        let goToGameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        goToGameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
        self.view?.presentScene(goToGameScene, transition:revealGameScene)
    }
}


class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var box = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        box = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        box.position = CGPoint.zero
        addChild(box)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

       if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

            if box.frame.contains(touchLocation) {

                let revealGameScene = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                let goToMenuScene = MenuScene(size: self.size)
                goToMenuScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
                self.view?.presentScene(goToMenuScene, transition:revealGameScene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```